# AWS Instance Metadata (linux console)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cloud, metadata, instance

I was trying to run instant metadata via linux console it keep returning Connection timed out error. can anyone help resolve this please.

curl http://169.254.169.154/latest/meta-data
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.154 port 80: Connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made a typo in IP address.

--> Correct: curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data

--> Incorrect: curl http://169.254.169.154/latest/meta-data